# Writing to MongoDB fails silently during Neo4j session.run() but works fine normally

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, neo4j

The problem is that everything works fine in isolation, but as soon as I combine the Log.create(obj) into the Neo4j result stream, it stops working and what I assume is some Promise behaviour is eating all log information so I can't figure out why exactly it's not working or how to force it to display meaningful information.

I have been trying to diagnose this for the past 2 days, but I can't figure out why.

I have 2 files:
example.js and E1Logger/index.js

The logger file is simply the schema and models for a method that writes an object to MongoDB. It works fine if I comment out the bottom half of example.js.

I've tried probably like 20 different combinations of chaining promises, catching, done, exec, making it more asynchronous, making it more synchronous, and I can't seem to get any meaningful information.

I'm dying to know what is required to make it work.

> example.js

```
 //var config = require('./config');
 const mongoose = require('mongoose');
 mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/major', error => { if (error) { console.error('ERROR: ' + error) }});
 //mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

 var neo4j = require('neo4j-driver').v1;
 var config = {};
 config.neo4jHost = 'bolt://localhost:7687';
 config.neo4jUser = 'neo4j';
 config.neo4jPassword = 'garbagepassword';
 var driver = neo4j.driver(config.neo4jHost, neo4j.auth.basic(config.neo4jUser, config.neo4jPassword));

 var E1Logger = require('./E1Logger');

 let newInfoLog = {
     logType: 'INFO',
     eventType: 'Purge Stale Invite',
     result: 'Success',
     invitedByUser: {
         neo4jNodeID: 123,
         name: 123 + ' ' + 321,
         email: 123
     },
     purgedUser: {
         neo4jNodeID: 123,
         email: 123
     },
     createdAt: 123,
     expirationAt: 123
 };

 let newErrorLog = {
     logType: 'ERROR',
     eventType: 'Purge Stale Invite',
     result: 'Fail',
     reason: 123,
     attemptedQuery: 123,
 };

 E1Logger.info(newInfoLog);

 E1Logger.error(newErrorLog);

 // Calculate cutoff time for expired invites and form the Cypher Query
 var currentTime = new Date().getTime();
 var sliceTime = currentTime - 604800000; // 604800000 milliseconds in one week
 var cypherQuery = 'MATCH (e:Person)-[r:INVITED_TO_APP]->(x) WHERE r.expirationAt<=\'' + sliceTime + '\' AND r.status=\'pending\' RETURN id(e) as invitedByUserId, e.given_name as invitedByUserFirstName, e.family_name as invitedByUserLastName, e.email as invitedByUserEmail, r.createdAt as createdAt, r.expirationAt as expirationAt, id(x) as purgedUserId, x.email as purgedUserEmail';

 // Execute Purge Event
 var session = driver.session();
 session
     .run(cypherQuery)
     .then(function(result){
         result.records.forEach(function(record) {
             // Generate log for each expired invite
             let newInfoLog = {
                 logType: 'INFO',
                 eventType: 'Purge Stale Invite',
                 result: 'Success',
                 invitedByUser: {
                     neo4jNodeID: record.get('invitedByUserId').low,
                     name: record.get('invitedByUserFirstName') + ' ' + record.get('invitedByUserLastName'),
                     email: record.get('invitedByUserEmail')
                 },
                 purgedUser: {
                     neo4jNodeID: record.get('purgedUserId').low,
                     email: record.get('purgedUserEmail')
                 },
                 createdAt: record.get('createdAt'),
                 expirationAt: record.get('expirationAt')
             };
             // Log result
             console.log('PURGED: ' + JSON.stringify(newInfoLog));
             E1Logger.info(newInfoLog);
         });
         session.close();
         driver.close();
     })
     .catch(function(error) {
         // Generate log for failed purge
         let newErrorLog = {
             logType: 'ERROR',
             eventType: 'Purge Stale Invite',
             result: 'Fail',
             reason: error,
             attemptedQuery: cypherQuery,
         };

         // Log result
         console.log('ERROR: ' + JSON.stringify(newErrorLog));
         E1Logger.error(newErrorLog);
         //session.close();
         //driver.close();
     });

 mongoose.disconnect();
```

> E1Logger/index.js

```
 const mongoose = require('mongoose');

 // Define Info Log Schema
 const InfoLogModel = mongoose.model('Infolog', new mongoose.Schema({
     logType: String,
     loggedAt: { type: Number, default: new Date().getTime() },
     eventType: String,
     result: String,
     invitedByUser: {
         neo4jNodeID: Number,
         name: String,
         email: String
     },
     purgedUser: {
         neo4jNodeID: Number,
         email: String
     },
     createdAt: Number,
     expirationAt: Number
 }));

 // Define Error Log Schema
 const ErrorLogModel = mongoose.model('Errorlog', new mongoose.Schema({
     logType: String,
     loggedAt: { type: Number, default: new Date().getTime() },
     eventType: String,
     result: String,
     reason: String,
     attemptedQuery: String,
 }));


 module.exports = {
     // Define Info Log Model
     info: function(eventData) {
         InfoLogModel.create(eventData, (error, addedEvent) => {
             if (error) throw error;
             console.log('INFO: ' + addedEvent);
         });
     },
     // Define Error Log Model
     error: function(eventData) {
         ErrorLogModel.create(eventData, (error, addedEvent) => {
             if (error) throw error;
             console.log('ERROR: ' + addedEvent);
         });
     }
 };
```

I suspect the problem is at `ErrorLogModel.create(eventData)`. I've never been able to get it to write to MongoDB from inside session.run(). A had a couple combinations that were showing something about a promise rejection, but that's as close as I got. I recall something like `ErrorLogModel.create(eventData).catch( err => console.log('ok') );` made it do that.

Am I missing something about promises here? Why does functional code working code through Neo4j `session.run().then()` cause it to stop working? Is it maybe a bug I should report to Mongoose or Neo4j?

Comment: I'm just wondering now, do I maybe need something like an anonymous function to make it run normally? Like, `session.run().then(var test = function() { InfoLogModel.create(eventData) })` TBH, I think I tried that earlier tonight and it stayed silently failing.

Comment: Remove `mongoose.disconnect()` in `example.js` and see if it starts working.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but I'd strongly recommend changing your overall approach to logging.  In most cases, it's far better to *not* bake all that logging logic into your own code.  Instead, just write to stdout.  It can be rich logging even if you are doing stdout by applying some consistency to the log messages.  If you want the logs to go in a database, use stdout redirection on the process running your node app to push the logs to the DB vs a file, or (better still) use some standard log utility like Logstash to ship them.  Have a look at http://12factor.net/

Comment: I ditched that attempt I posted about here. I appreciate your mention of 12factor. I didn't realize I was violating it. I have since came to understand stdout and stderr better. Thanks for your mention. I hope others find it valuable as well.

Comment: I've also skilled up significantly on promises and sync behaviour, so I can see some significant flaws in the logic here related to that. 

I think robertklep is dead on with the mongoose driver closing. It would have abruptly closed before the code even ran.